# Write an applet that displays “UT” in blue in a yellow circle

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

Write an applet that displays “UT” in blue in a yellow circle
Here is the code

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

g.setColor(Color.blue);
Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 72);
g.setFont(f);
g.drawString("UT.", 10, 30);
g.fillOval(100,100,100,100);

}
```

Comment: What does "set text in circle" mean?

Answer (score 1):

To draw a string horizontally: [`java.awt.Graphics2D.drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float%29)

Choose a font, and apply it to the graphics context with [`java.awt.Graphics.setFont()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29)

To know the text extends: [`java.awt.FontMetrics.stringWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29)

To learn how to use 2D graphics in Java: *[The Java Tutorial: Trail: 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)*

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Application extends Frame {

   class DrawingText extends Canvas {

      private static final String LABEL  = "In a circle";
      private static final int    MARGIN = 8;

      @Override
      public void paint( Graphics g ) {
         super.paint( g );
         Font pretty = new Font( "Lucida Sans Demibold", Font.BOLD, 12 );
         g.setFont( pretty );
         FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
         int width = fm.stringWidth( LABEL );
         int tx    = getWidth ()/2 - width/2;
         int ty    = getHeight()/2 + fm.getAscent()/4;
         int cx    = tx - MARGIN;
         int cy    = getHeight()/2 - width/2 - MARGIN;
         g.drawString( LABEL, tx, ty );
         g.drawArc( cx, cy, width+2*MARGIN, width+2*MARGIN, 0, 360 );
     }
   }

   Application() {
      super( "UT in a circle" );
      add( new DrawingText());
      setSize( 300, 300 );
      setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
         @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit( 0 ); }});
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      new Application().setVisible( true );
   }
}
```

Comment: Dont know ho to use them for that purpose i am beginer please help

Comment: *"Dont know ho to use them for that purpose"*  Now is a good time to try something..  I note this question already has 2 down-votes.  I am thinking because it really shows no sign of effort.  Don't expect people to know of your previous questions - each one should stand on its own.

Comment: So please help me @AndrewThompson 
I will be very thankful to u

Comment: *"So please help me"* I just **tried** to help you.  Try something, then [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16320295/edit) with your attempt!

Comment: Help me please @AndrewThompson